# Please explain PHP's documentation on session_destroy

Tags: php, session

I am reading [this](https://www.php.net/session_destroy).

`session_destroy() destroys all of the data associated with the current session.` 
Clears session data in the persistent storage. I get this.

`It does not unset any of the global variables associated with the session, or unset the session cookie.` 
The session variables are still in memory. I get this too.

`To use the session variables again, session_start() has to be called.` 
This is what I don't get! The session variables are still in memory. I can keep using it. Why do they specifically point out to call session_start() to use the variables again.

For example consider the following code -

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['first_name'] = "Foo";
$_SESSION['last_name'] = "Bar";
session_destroy();
echo $_SESSION['first_name'] . "<br>"; // I am able to do this, since the session data is still in memory. But I didn't need to call session_start(). So why does the documentation mention it?
```

Comment: You can use them but they will not be saved.

Comment: Are you sure that after destroying the session and set a value in a session key, you still get that value **after** the php refresh without `session_start()`?

Comment: Not after the refresh. But the documentation goes like this `To use the session variables again, session_start() has to be called. ` It doesn't really tell whether its for the same request-response cycle or for subsequent cycles.

Comment: Sidenote: If you put a link outside your PHP (in your first file) I.e.: `<a href="see_session.php">See if first name session will echo</a>` and place `session_start(); echo $_SESSION['first_name'] . "<br>";` in that file, you will see that `Foo` will not appear because the session has in fact, been destroyed. (*If that answers any doubt*) @user1720897

Comment: @Fred-ii- You must be implying that the session is destroyed for any subsequent requests. That I understand. I just wasn't sure whether the documentation is talking about the current request or subsequent requests. It looks like they must be talking about subsequent requests

Comment: All instances of the session on a single page will still show, even though `session_destroy();` is included. Yet, since `session_start();` is inside the "only" file being used and you're echoing `echo $_SESSION['first_name'] . "<br>";` then it's normal for it to be echo'ed after `session_destroy();`, because it has already been declared/assigned and session is still active. You just won't be able to access that variable on any other page. So, if you don't want it to be echo'ed on that page, then don't echo it "after" `session_destroy();`

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's what they meant by that. I must admit that I too have a bit of a hard time understanding the PHP.net documentation sometimes. It's like they expect us to have that embedded in our DNA soon as we're born! lol

Comment: Another sidenote: If you add the following after `echo $_SESSION['first_name'] . "<br>";` you will see that it will not echo the session variable (using `unset()`) `unset($_SESSION['first_name']); echo "<hr>"; echo $_SESSION['first_name'] . "<br>";`

Answer (score 0):

It is because the `$_SESSION` array still exists/has been declared when `session_start()` is called. So if you want to re-create the array again calling `session_start` is the only way to do it.

If you made a second request after the destroy and did not call `session_start` you would find the `$_SESSION` array to be empty.